# How to correctly transfer the env from code to k8s?

Tags: mongodb, go, kubernetes

The app on Golang have some strings:

```
type configuration struct {
    ListenPort    string `env:"listen" default:":8080"`
    MongoHost     string `env:"mongo_host" default:"mongo-srv:27017"`
    MongoUser     string `env:"mongo_user" default:"user"`
    MongoPass     string `env:"mongo_pass" default:"password"`
    MongoDBname   string `env:"mongo_db_name" default:"MyDB"`
}
```

How I can transfer values from evnironment to deploy this app in k8s?
I tried to do so. But it doesn't work.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: MyApp
  namespace: App
...
    spec:
      containers:
...
        env:
          - name: listen
            value: "8080"
          - name: mongo_host
            value: "mongo-srv:27017"
...
```

Comment: How can you tell it doesn't work?  If you run the Go code outside Kubernetes, are those same environment-variable settings honored?

Comment: When I run pod with app, it can't connect to the db. Maybe I am using environment variables incorrectly. Is it worth removing these parameters from the code, but additionally writing it down in the docker compose?

Comment: are you trying to extract the struct values from go code to the pod/container ?

Comment: @shubham_asati Yes.

Comment: can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve .. put some more info about the scenario